# Application.js is not being processed into final view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have in my `application.html.erb` layout a line like this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

but in the html page sent to the browser I find only

```
<script src="/assets/application.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" media="all" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

which contains 'nothing'

```
(function() {

}).call(this);
```

---

In my `/app/assets/javascripts/application.js` I have

```
//= require jquery.min
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min
```

and my `/vendor/assets/javascripts/` include `jquery.min.js` and `bootstrap.min`

my `Gemfile` include

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sprockets-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
```

my workaround for now is to include the jquery and bootstrap javascripts directly with

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

---

#### Useful information

```
$uname -a
Linux Kasama 4.0.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jun 23 14:25:08 CEST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$rails --version
Rails 4.2.3

$ruby --version
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]
```

Source code for the whole application can be found [here](https://github.com/Kasama/blacklist) (any constructive critic is appreciated)

---

From what I've read from [The Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), what I have should work properly, but it's not.

---

Side note: the application.css manifest gets loaded correctly and the bootstrap.css file gets sent to browser, the problem only happens with javascript files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See **In Development** section of the doc:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-development

> In development mode, assets are served as separate files in the order they are specified in the manifest file.

Your js/css assets are there, in separated script/link tags.

**Update** In your case trouble was caused by `application.coffee` file which presents alongside with `application.js`. Removing it will fix your problem.

Comment: That's exactly the problem, they are not being served at all, the only `<script>` tag there is in the final view is the application.self-<hash>.js

Comment: I can github it, just give me a second

Comment: @Kasama please see update to my answer. You should simply delete `application.coffee` file in `assets/javascripts`

Comment: That did actually solve my problem. I didn't think that could be the problem, as I have a `application.css` and `application.css.sass` in the stylesheets folder. Thanks, it was driving me nuts